# Why don't browsers throw an error when any other word is used in place of 'javascript' in the value of onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I inherited a website, and just came across this curiosity:

```
<a href="/delete"  onClick="jamoscript:return confirm('Do you really want to do that?');">Delete all</a>
```

I can display the page containing it and click the link to get the confirmation dialog box exactly the same as I do when I change "`jamoscript`" to "`javascript`". No diagnostics are displayed in the Firebug console, either when the page is loaded or when the link is clicked. What the hey? Googling for jamoscript doesn't turn up anything interesting.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The string value of an "onclick" attribute is taken to be simple JavaScript code. JavaScript includes provisions for [labeled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), so that code is a `return` statement with the label "jamoscript". In other words, this:

```
jamoscript: return confirm("Do you really want to hurt me?");
```

is perfectly legal JavaScript. Labels aren't used much, so they're unfamiliar.

The only context in which the "javascript:" prefix matters is when a URL is expected, as is the case with the "href" attribute of `<a>` tags.

Comment: This question is making me really wish that the language had been called "JamoScript".

Comment: Haha! This was like an optical illusion. My brain was aware of the facts you stated so clearly, but the code tricked me into reading it as something else. We won't get fooled (by this one) again!

Comment: This reminds me of the famous problem of what the following does: `function foo(a) { x: 2 }`.

Comment: @StephanMuller it doesn't do anything; the puzzle is that it *looks* invalid (like a muddle of a function declaration with an object initializer), but it's valid. The portion `x: 2` is a perfectly valid JavaScript statement (and it doesn't do anything).

Comment: I created an account here, just to tell you that this line of code(? -I am not a programmer) was without any doubt written by a Greek, or at least "jamoscirpt" was proposed by a Greek. "Jamo" is how one would attempt to use the sounds of the English letters to produce the sound that the word  "f---ing" has in the Greek language. So if you try to read aloud "jamoscript", a Greek person that knows the word "script" will understand "f---ing script". The intended effect would be more certain if instead of "j" the letter "g" was used, but I guess there was the intended play with "j-ava".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos wow that's awesome. If anything, it makes me wish even **more** that the language were actually called "JamoScript" :)

Comment: My favorite version of this was just sticking a random URL in the code.  Without a syntax highlighter, it's not immediately obvious that `http://www.google.com/` is valid.  Bonus when it appears in C...

Comment: @asawyer I appreciate the info (+1), but please don't tempt me to shed my meek on-line persona and revert back to my real one...

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos The code was actually written by a programmer in India. I doubt he spoke Greek. I wonder if there's any connection to Hindi. The only language connection I could find by googling (oviously not going to find Greek since it's not an exact word match) is that the letters of the Korean Hangul script are called jamo. I also doubt he spoke Korean...

Comment: @sootsnoot The plot thickens, then. Are you sure he had no Greek friends?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Looks like you've had an account for almost a year, as you answered a question back in December '13. Nice try, but I see through your ruse. </joking>

Comment: @FreeAslnBeer Yeah I had forgotten about it. Some jamo migration of a question I had answered in Cross Validated I think it was.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Afraid I have no way of knowing for certain. I only know that it was written by an Indian programmer at an Indian company in India. But I don't know exactly which of several programmers at the company wrote it, and no longer have contact with the people who were involved in the project. The code they wrote was strange in many ways - but this is the strangest thing yet.

Comment: @sootsnoot Well, this proves that _not_ having enough information may be a good thing, since it can fire the imagination. I challenge anybody to come up with a better _story_ for the movie currently titled "jamo: the Greek Connection".